# Delete User Unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am new to unit testing and I dont always "see" what needs to be tested. Currently I am creating  unit test to verify that a user has been deleted from the app.

Here is what I have so far. Can anyone take a look a this and make some recommendations for other things to test or have I covered most of it for a delete user account?

```
            MembershipProvider prov = this.GetMembershipProvider();
            MembershipCreateStatus status;
            MembershipUser user = prov.CreateUser("UserX", "12345", "test.UserX@abc.com", "", "", true, null, out status);

            //call get user
            user = prov.GetUser("UserX", false); 

            //Deletes user and all related information
            prov.DeleteUser("UserX", true);

            // Try to retrieve user again
            user = prov.GetUser("UserX", false);

            //test to see if user has been deleted
            Assert.AreEqual(null, user);
```

Comment: It looks okay; Before that one you should have another that creates a user and tests if it's created correctly

Comment: Thanks. I do and its a work in progress. I got stuck and wanted to move on to something else.

Comment: You may want to find cases that should fail (i.e. trying to delete a user that doesn't exist) and make sure that they do fail in the expected manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that the `status` and `user` is what you expect after the call to `CreateUser()`.

After your first call to `user = prov.GetUser("UserX", false);` you should check that `user` is what you expect.  For example, check it is not null and the username is correct.

It's not clear whether `DeleteUser()` has a return value or not.  If it does, then make sure that value is checked.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a lot more like an integration test than a unit test.  I say this because I am assuming the `GetUser`, `DeleteUser` method make database calls.  So, there are multiple units at work, including: creation of the user object, persistence of the user object to the database, deletion of the user object, and attempted retrieval of the user object.

That being said, you should be asserting your assumptions after each state change, because as written your method doesn't prove anything.  Literally, each method could ignore all the input parameters and return null - and your test would pass.  You're going to want to make sure that the user exists in the first place before you can be certain that you've deleted it.

Imagine that your `MembershipProvider` has implementation like:

```
    public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {
          public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, stringpasswordAnswer , bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, ref MembershipCreateStatus  status)
          {
              status = default(MembershipCreateStatus);
              return default(MembershipUser);
          }          

          public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool login)
          {
              return default(MembershipUser);
          }

          public override bool DeleteUser(string username, bool deleteRelatedData)
          {
              return default(bool);
          }
     }
```

With this code all your tests would pass, and you would walk aways thinking that the membership feature of the application works correctly, when it actually doesn't do a thing at all.  In general, **a good way to see if your unit tests are useful, is to try to break them.**  If the you can make your unit test lie, then you wrote it wrong.